# oAuth 2.0 and exposed APIs

Tags: oauth-2.0

We have a web portail using some exposed API from a service desk application to create and list tickets. oAuth 2.0 is used to authenticate the requests through Google server. Below is the roles of the differents components :

- Google oAuth 2.0 : Authentication server
- Service Desk application : Resource server with exposed API
- Client : Web portail

Which oAuth fow i have to use to authenticate the requests from the client to the resource server ? I think it's the client credentials.

How to check when the resource server receives a request that the request is authorized and can access the resource ? Currently, the resource server checks the access token provided with the request through the authorization server Google (using the API useremail endpoint), then, the resource server checks locally in a file if the client_id is declared.

Any help will be welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the token at the web portal, you probably want to use the Implicit flow. The Resource Owner Password Credentials flow has some problems:

- It requires a client password, which cannot be stored safely in a browser,
- Your web portal gets the username and password (of a portal user), which is not good from the security standpoint

You cannot handle authorization of your own application (Service Desk) using Google access tokens, because they contain only Google-related scopes (for accessing Google services and resources). You can either do it locally - have some mapping between Google users and local roles or to have your own OAuth2 server with your own scopes that accepts Google authentication (for example KeyCloak).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ok, so i cannot create my own scope in the Google Authorization server, i did'nt know that. Currently, i check the acess token transmitted with the request (check the validity), the token is transmistted trhough a JWT token. Next i check if the client id is existing in a file containing all the client_id authorized to access the resource server. My provider would like to add an audience token to check if the client is authorized to access the specified resourcer server.